# Adding space generates new line JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, pug

When I add .html(variable + " |") it generates a new line however in another variable it works perfect.

Working code in js

```
$(".timeRema").html(secondsDoubleDig(timeRema) + " |")
------------------------------------------------------
.timeRema {
    position: absolute;
    top: 764;
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    left: 700
}
```

[image]

Not working code in js and css

```
$(".dirTime").html(convertSecToMin(dirTime) + " |");
----------------------------------------------------
.dirTime {
    position: absolute;
    top: 764;
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    left: 1190
}
```

[image]

However if i dont add the space, it works.

```
$(".dirTime").html(convertSecToMin(dirTime) + "||");
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're using, but why is there JS with the CSS? Feels kinda duh why the code is not working...

Comment: Is there enough width for the longer line? Try using `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space)

Answer (score 1):

Solved thanks to ΔO 'delta zero'

I do have more space in the width because I have more stuff far right.
[image]

but I didnt know why it wasnt working but with   it works smoothly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because .dirTime has a higher `left` value, so there is less space for the " |" string and it breaks into the next line. Try decreasing `left: 1190` to `left: 700`